# How to put overflowed widgets in the next column in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of Widgets and I'm representing them in a row. Now the list is quite large so I want the overflowed widgets to be shown in the next line, and repeat the same in the next line. How can i do it without using ListView.

My code:

```
Row(
    children: tags,
)
```

Here tags is a list of widgets. All the widgets have same hight and variable width.

Comment: try  Wrap instead of row

Comment: warp row with SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Wrap` widget.

```
Wrap(
       direction: Axis.horizontal,
       children: tags),
```